# Where is Cesna (City) in Russland from 1909 ship manifest of Polish grandmother?

Tags: immigration, manifest, poland

My grandmother's ship manifest states her city of origin as Cesna Russland.

She is Polish.

Does anyone have any idea what or where Cesna is?

Comment: Hi, Marilyn, welcome to G&FH.SE.  I'm not an expert in Eastern Europe, but I wonder if it could be [Cisna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisna)? I searched on [JewishGen](http://www.jewishgen.org/) in the 'search for a town box' and they give alternate spellings of "Cieszyn [Pol], Těšín [Cz], Teschen [Ger], Tessin [Lat]". Cisna is one of the towns listed in the [Geisher-Galicia Database](http://www.geshergalicia.org/towns/cisna/).   Is this passenger list the only clue you have?

Comment: Cisna was definitely in Galicia, in Austro-Hungarian empire. Cieszyn/Těšín/Teschen as well, and it's nowhere near where the border with Russia was, I'm afraid both those are missed guesses.

Answer (score 3):

[Cisna, Poland](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Cisna,+Poland/@49.3375674,22.4946785,9z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x473bfc2177046573:0xfdb050ee20ced469) looks to be not far from Ukrainian & Hungarian boarders today but it has not always been that way. I looked for multiple other variations of Cisna / Cesna and Cieszyn and couldn't find any other references except for ones that brought me back to this area of what is today Poland.

I found this [1909 map of Russia that shows Cisna where Galisiya (Галиция)](http://www.davidrumsey.com/luna/servlet/detail/RUMSEY~8~1~255675~5519963:No-14--Karta-Evropeyskaia-Rossiia--?sort=pub_list_no_initialsort%2Cpub_date%2Cpub_list_no%2Cseries_no&fullTextSearch=fullTextSearch&qvq=q:Rossiia;sort:pub_list_no_initialsort%2Cpub_date%2Cpub_list_no%2Cseries_no;lc:RUMSEY~8~1&mi=2&trs=35)  in the country labeled as Vengria (Венгрия in Russian) which is today Hungary. It is a bit hard to read so I am including a marked up version as well below.

Note: It was not part of Russia, but if they were "Russian Sounding" that may have been why they were labeled as from Russland. I also found reference to Cisna & Russland in a [document here](http://www.pospichal.net/lokstatistik/51802-cisna.htm).

Marked Up: 
Note I cannot completely make it out but it kind of looks like Cesna in the vertical text. A key thing to note is Cisna/Cesna is at a cross-roads which helped identify it. The map below is also slightly tilted.
[image]

Today:
[image]